# Не сохраняется приложение

Tags: android, android-studio

Использую телефон для запуска приложения, раньше при компиляции приложения через Android Studio, оно сохранялось на телефоне. Сейчас после компиляции приложения просто открывается, но самой программы нет (то есть чтобы запустить программу нужно опять ее скомпилировать). 
Пробовал добавить файл app-debug.apk и потом установить приложение. Написало что установка прошла успешно, но приложения нет в меню. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

- Другие приложения сохраняются.

Comment: Возможно вы что-то изменили в настройках или просто не можете найти его.(скрыли его в меню). Я считаю само по себе такое произойти не могло, по крайней мере за годы работы в Android Studio такого не случалось у меня. Попробуйте перезагрузить AS или пересобрать проект.

Comment: Пробывал пересобрать проект, то самое.

Comment: Покажите манифест. Может вы там убрали у активити фильтр нужный

Comment: в Manifest файле изменения происходили хоть какие?

Comment: Была ошибка в манифесте. Спасибо.

Comment: Будет просто замечательно, если вы не просто напишите "все пучком, сделал уже ..", а оформите найденное вами решение в качестве ответа на ваш вопрос. Это возможно поможет другим участникам в будущем быстрее решить аналогичную проблему.

Comment: Если у кого то будет подобная проблема, я с радостью ему помогу. Могу только сказать что у меня была не нужная строчка в не нужном месте, ето чисто моя невнимательность.